# iOS VoiceOver crash (message sent to deallocated instance)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

I am getting a weird crash when running my app with VoiceOver enabled. The app has a sidebar interface (like Facebook). When tapping on one of the `UITableViewCell`s in the sidebar `UITableView`, I swap out the view controller (create a new one based on which cell was tapped and deallocate the old one).

While VoiceOver is enabled, I *sometimes* get a crash when I tap the cell. This crash does not occur every time (it is about once every two or three tries) and this is not the only thing that causes the crash (but in my testing it is the main thing that triggers it).

Keep in mind this crash **only** happens then VoiceOver is enabled.

I usually get this line in the console when the crash occurs.

> *** -[UITableTextAccessibilityElement setAccessibilityLabel:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1fdaec10

but I have also seen

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
>   Note then I see the `NSRangeException` with exception breakpoints enabled, it does not point me to a place in my code where the error occured.

So I enabled NSZombies and ran the app in Instruments. The object references was never touched by any of my code.
[image: Instruments running NSZombies]

I also tried getting a crash log when running outside of the debugger, but unfortunatly Xcode was not able to symbolicate them.

> Last Exception Backtrace:
>
> 0   CoreFoundation                    0x2e3c3f46 __exceptionPreprocess + 126
>
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x387536aa objc_exception_throw + 34
>
> 2   CoreFoundation                    0x2e2fa52e -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 226
>
> 3   APP-NAME                      0x000e3726 0x46000 + 644902
>
> 4   UIKit                             0x0250462e 0x24c6000 + 255534
>
> 5   UIAccessibility                   0x35c029f8 -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) accessibilityElementCount] + 16
>
> 6   UIAccessibility                   0x35bfe66a _appendChildrenToArrayStartingAtIndexWithChildren + 318
>
> 7   UIAccessibility                   0x35bfe51e _appendChildrenToArrayStartingAtIndex + 86
>
> 8   UIAccessibility                   0x35bfe460 _addAXElementsToArrayFromObject + 1580
>
> 9   UIAccessibility                   0x35bfddfc _appendVendedAXElementsFromUIElements + 156
>
> 10  UIAccessibility                   0x35bfdbfe _createAXUIElementsFromUIElements + 126
>
> 11  UIAccessibility                   0x35bfc218 _copyParameterizedAttributeValueCallback 
>   + 152
>
> 12  AXRuntime                         0x3152395c _AXXMIGCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 168
>
> 13  AXRuntime                         0x3152084e _XCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 438
>
> 14  AXRuntime                         0x31528158 mshMIGPerform + 184
>
> 15  CoreFoundation                    0x2e38e9da **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 30
>
> 16  CoreFoundation                    0x2e38e976 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
>
> 17  CoreFoundation                    0x2e38d14a __CFRunLoopRun + 1394
>
> 18  CoreFoundation                    0x2e2f7c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
>
> 19  CoreFoundation                    0x2e2f7a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
>
> 20  GraphicsServices                  0x32fd627e GSEventRunModal + 134
>
> 21  UIKit                             0x30b9b044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
>
> 22  APP-NAME                          0x000509e2 0x46000 + 43490
>
> 23  libdyld.dylib                     0x38c5bab2 tlv_initializer + 2

The crash occurs on iOS 6 and 7. I also tried removing every accessibility call from the entire app, but the app was still crashing.

I have been trying to figure this out all week and do not feel like I am getting any closer. Any ideas on where to proceed from here?

Comment: We can't help you without relevant pieces of code to look at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were able to find the problem by debugging on iOS 6 instead of 7.

In iOS 6,

> AX ERROR: Could not find my mock parent, most likely I am stale.

was showing up in the console. That combined with the `UITableViewCell` error mentioned about, we dug through all of the table code in the sidebar.

We found that we were using reusable `UITableViewCells` as header views, and that was causing the zombie issue that we were seeing.

So bottom line, don't use `UITableViewCells` as `UITableView` header/footer view.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error. I removed the accessibility methods to get rid of tis error. 
We need to overwrite few accessibility methods to support reading order by voiceover in iOS 6

```
- (id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [[self accessibleElements] objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element
{
    return [[self accessibleElements] indexOfObject:element];
}
```

If your code is crashing based on the above methods I feel. Try to remove those methods and check. One thing I observed is after removing the above methods Voiceover will not read the elements in order. It will read in some other(random) order.

Hope this will fix your crash.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue, but I don't understand why only UITableViewCell/Header/Footer requires the manual handling of accessibleElements related methods.

Comment: Its just my observation : For Voiceover all the elements should know early it will not encourage adding elements in the middle. In tableview every time when we scroll elements gets loaded if those are coming from server it will be even more difficult for voiceover to recognize the container methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this crash if you try to manually focus accessibility on to a UITableViewCell instead of a particular item inside the cell. If your requirement is to treat the tableCell as a whole as an accessibility element then in addition to specifying accessibility label and trait for the cell forget not to set `isAccessibilityElement = YES` for the cell. If `isAccessibilityElement = YES` then the iOS will not attempt to call `[UITableTextAccessibilityElement setAccessibilityLabel:]`method which causes the crash because it knows that tableCell itself is an accessibility element and will not try to examine what is inside the cell.